# Configure eslint to report only plugin specific errors

Tags: eslint

Can eslint be configured to report only a certain subset of errors without explicitly settings all other rules as `false`

My use case is I want to have a separate report for `a11y` related errors coming from `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`

So I have a package scripts like

```json
"lint": "eslint .",
"lint.a11y": "eslint --no-eslintrc -c .eslintrc.a11y.js .",
```

The general config used in `lint` covers everything and is used in the IDE and during CI to validate code style

The `lin.a11y` serves only to provide a report on accessibility violations

Currently I use something like this (the idea was borrowed from [eslint:all](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-eslintall)):

```js
const builtInRules = require('eslint/lib/rules');

const disabledRules = {};

for (const [ruleId, rule] of builtInRules) {
  if (!rule.meta.deprecated) {
    disabledRules[ruleId] = 'off';
  }
}

module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: ['plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended'],
  plugins: ['jsx-a11y'],
  rules: {
    // Lint only a11y, disable other js style related rules
    ...disabledRules,
  },
};
```

This almost works, but when there exception to the rules disabled with code comments (disable rule for the line). I'll get an error like "Definition for rule ... was not found":

> Definition for rule 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' was not found  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

So now I have to import my default eslint configuration, extend it, disable any rules defined there, disable any other rules coming from other plugins, just so that errors for inline comments are disregarded

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom eslint reported that will:

- print a general output for all errors including `a11y`
- save a report containing only `a11y` errors/warnings

custom-lint-formatter.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const fileFormatter = require('eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/html');
const outputFormatter = require('eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/stylish');

function formatter(results = [], data) {
  saveA11yReport(results, data);
  const output = outputFormatter(results, data);

  return output;
}

function saveA11yReport(results, data) {
  // a11y errors and warnings
  const a11yRelated = results
    .filter(r => r.messages.some(m => m.ruleId.startsWith('jsx-a11y/')))
    .map(r => {
      const messages = r.messages.filter(m => m.ruleId.startsWith('jsx-a11y/'));

      return {
        ...r,
        messages,
        errorCount: messages.filter(m => m.severity == 2).length,
        warningCount: messages.filter(m => m.severity == 1).length,
      };
    });

  const a11yHtml = fileFormatter(a11yRelated, data);

  fs.writeFileSync('./dist/a11y.report.html', a11yHtml, 'utf8');
}

module.exports = formatter;
```

usage:

```sh
eslint -f ./custom-lint-formatter.js "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
```